# Copy row and related table row with new ID

Tags: sql

I've 2 tables, `schedule` and `scheduleEvent`. It's a one-to-many relationship.
I want to copy the rows of `schedule` with new `scheduleID` but also copy each related row of `shceduleEvent` also with new `shceduleEventID`, all based on a request.

The main goal is to copy `schedule`/`scheduleEvent` from one device to another; the only thing changing will be the device.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: will new ids start from 1?

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? Writing the SQL? Or programming?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that schedule and scheduleevent tables are connected with schedule id. in below query i selected all the schedules and schedule events with new ids. .( Please ignore typo or format since I am answering from phone)

**To  get scheduler table with new ids:**

```
with newschedule as (
select *, row_number() over( order by sheduleid) newscheduleid from schedule),
newsheduleevent as ( select *,  row_number() over (order by sheduleeventid)  newscheduleeventid, ns.newscheduleid
from scheduleevent se nner join newschedule ns on se.sheduleid=ns.scheduleid)
select * from newschedule
```

**To get newscheduleevent with new newscheduleeventid:**

```
with newschedule as (
select *, row_number() over( order by sheduleid) newscheduleid from schedule),
newsheduleevent as ( select *,  row_number() over (order by sheduleeventid)  newscheduleeventid, ns.newscheduleid
from scheduleevent se nner join newschedule ns on se.sheduleid=ns.scheduleid)
select * from newscheduleevent
```